# is there a good example out there for XML Sign with XADES-EPES in Java?

Tags: java, xml-signature, xades4j

I try to use **xades4j** but The documentation is a little generalized.
in this moment I have a basic sign method but don't get the xml tags that I need.

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_TYPE);

    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

    PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS, PRIVATE_KEY_PASSWORD.toCharArray());

    File signatureFile = new File("./invoice.xml");

    String  baseURI = signatureFile.toURL().toString(); // BaseURI para las URL Relativas.

    // Instanciamos un objeto XMLSignature desde el Document. El algoritmo de firma será DSA
    // Signature - Required DSAwithSHA1 (DSS)
    XMLSignature xmlSignature = new XMLSignature(document, baseURI, XMLSignature.ALGO_ID_SIGNATURE_DSA);

    // Añadimos el nodo de la firma a la raiz antes de firmar.
    // Observe que ambos elementos pueden ser mezclados en una forma con referencias separadas
    document.getDocumentElement().appendChild(xmlSignature.getElement());

    // Creamos el objeto que mapea: Document/Reference
    Transforms transforms = new Transforms(document);
    transforms.addTransform(Transforms.TRANSFORM_BASE64_DECODE); // TRANSFORM_ENVELOPED_SIGNATURE

    // Añadimos lo anterior Documento / Referencia
    // ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1 = "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1";
    xmlSignature.addDocument("", transforms, Constants.ALGO_ID_DIGEST_SHA1);

    // Añadimos el KeyInfo del certificado cuya clave privada usamos
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(PRIVATE_KEY_ALIAS);
    xmlSignature.addKeyInfo(cert);
    xmlSignature.addKeyInfo(cert.getPublicKey());

    // Realizamos la firma
    xmlSignature.sign(privateKey);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using xades4j, have a look at a test case.

Start here:

https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/blob/master/src/test/java/xades4j/production/SignerEPESTest.java

Comment: @mposadar the code you showed seems to only be using Apache Santuario, which is the underlying library for xades4j. The link shared above and https://github.com/luisgoncalves/xades4j/wiki  should get you started.